# Scrolling with MacBook trackpad: Is it possible to do with only one finger while a key pressed?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, keyboard, trackpad

The normal way to scroll on a MacBook trackpad is to use two-finger scrolling.

Is it possible to scroll with one finger as follows:

1. Press and hold a key-modifier (e.g. ctrl/alt etc).
2. Scroll using one finger like it is two fingers, while key pressed.

Answer (score 7):

What works for me is [Scroll](https://ryanhanson.dev/scroll) tool that allows you to enable single finger scrolling on the trackpad side. I got the idea from this [superuser thread](https://superuser.com/questions/666035/one-finger-scrolling-on-a-macbook-touchpad)

Comment: This software is no longer free - allowing a 20 day trial - but I just tried it and works great straight away. Pretty sure I got arm pain from constant two-finger scrolling for my work, so this should be very helpful.